# Jquery formatting a date

Tags: jquery, date

The user selects a date, and I am trying to add a full year to this date:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.input-group.date').change(function() {
        var $input = $(this).find('input.form-control');


        var effdateid = $input.attr('id');
        var expdateid =  effdateid.replace("effective","expire");

        var myDate = new Date($input.val());
        myDate.setFullYear(myDate.getFullYear() + 1);

        if( !$("#" + expdateid).val() ) {
            $("#" + expdateid).val(myDate)
        }
    })
});
```

But the date is coming out as e.g. Mon Jul 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

I want it as mm/dd/yyyy i.e 07/18/2016

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you could do formatting like below

```
var dateFormatted = myDate.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + myDate.getDate() + "/" + myDate.getFullYear();
$("#" + expdateid).val(dateFormatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Date Format for **mm/dd/yyyy**

```
var date = new Date('Mon Jul 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400');
var dateFormat = date.getMonth() + 1)  + "/" + date.getDate()  + "/" +  date.getFullYear();
console.log(dateFormat);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tsv1t096/)